# Shift a series to the right in tensorboard

Tags: tensorboard

I ran two training runs where the second one started where the first left off. However, tensorboard doesn't know that the training runs are related to each other and just display them as two separate series:

[image]

Is there any way I can manually shift the pink series to the right, so that it begins where the first one left off?